# Insert statement on asp.net not inserting on mysql table

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I am creating a web form on asp.net that will allow the end user to assign multiple users bassed on a selected department to a quiz..

the database is mysql database since I use joomla

the tables on mysql are:  jos_users_quizzes with the following columns:

```
id
quiz_id
user_id
```

I have a second is called called

jos_dhruprofile with this columns

```
id
name
username
department
```

I need to select all user ids from selected department and insert those id into the user_quizzes table.

I have two queries trying to to insert the first one which has the condition for selected department doesnt work while 
the one without the were statement actually inserts, I get no errors , just the insertion doesnt go..

```
 string quizidselected = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
   string deptselected = ListBox2.SelectedValue;
   OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id) SELECT uid, ' " + quizidselected + " ' FROM jos_dhruprofile WHERE department = ' " + deptselected.ToString() + " '"); 
          // OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id)    SELECT uid, ' " + quizidselected + " ' FROM dhruprofile ");
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR LOOKING MY CODE

Full code

Code from and ASP.NET form to insert ....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

     private void InsertRecords(StringCollection sc)
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=appdevelsvr;database=xxxx;uid=xx;pwd=xx;";
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            string quizidselected = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            string deptselected = ListBox2.SelectedValue;
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id) SELECT uid, ' " + quizidselected + " ' FROM jos_dhruprofile WHERE department = ' " + deptselected.ToString() + " '"); 
          // OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id)    SELECT uid, ' " + quizidselected + " ' FROM dhruprofile "); 

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", true);
            Response.Write(deptselected.ToString());
           // Response.Write(sql.ToString());

        }

        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);

        }

        finally
        {

            conn.Close();

        }

    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();

        foreach (ListItem item in ListBox2.Items)
        {

            if (item.Selected)
            {
                sc.Add(item.Text);

            }


        } 

                InsertRecords(sc);

    }


}
```

Comment: what is the value coming into this statement `string deptselected = ListBox2.SelectedValue` . Have you tried taking the command query and executing it directly on your Db with the where clause?

Comment: I added php beacuse the query I am sending out through odbc is to a mysql database, I know mysql is designed to work with php, so meabe a simmilar troubleshooting techinque would work on my code/

Comment: Try the select query separately and see if it returns anything.

Comment: @TonyR saying mysql was designed for PHP is like saying MSSQL is designed for VBA. PHP happens to have mysql support, but it's not DESIGNED to support it.

Comment: mysql can work with C++, C#, Python ... and other programmings, it's just an database storage engine, PHP doesn't have almost anything to do with MySQL.

Comment: Ashley, this doesnt work either when executing on phpmyadmin...INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id)
  SELECT uid, '1' FROM jos_dhruprofile WHERE department = 'IT'

Comment: This doesnt do what I need, do I need alias?

Comment: this -SELECT uid, '1' FROM jos_dhruprofile WHERE department = 'IT'

Comment: What are the data types of the columns in the relevant tables?  Also, when you run just the select portion in phpmyadmin, what do you get back?

Comment: @Tony . Are you getting any error? Do you have a department like 'IT' in your jos_dhruprofile

Comment: yes i have two values with IT,,,,    actually is weird beacuse if I use Like  it does pull the uid I need  LIKE '% IT %'

Comment: So what can be wrong then ,  I do get the uid's but have to use LIKE.

Comment: Now I actually see and error: 1 Duplicate entry '246-1' for key 'uc_UserQ' SQL1.sql 1 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the query you want us to debug is the one with the where clause.

Please set a breakpoint at the line where you are creating a new odbc command for cmd. You need to check the value of 'deptselected'.

Alternatively, you can debug.writeline the SQL statement and copy-paste it into a SQL query UI. Please run the select by itself. I think it will not return any rows because either 'deptselected' doesn't exist in your table or 'deptselected' is empty.

Also, two good programming pointers:-

1). Use parameterized SQL statements instead of appending values into the string. Your code is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. This is very bad.

2). 'deptselected' is already a string, you do not need to 'ToString' it again.

Hope this helps.

Edit:-
I just read the comments above. Do a select * (star) on that table and where someother_column = another_value to get the same row that you are interested in. Check the string lenght of your department column. Check if you have spaces at the beginning of the string or after.

Comment: something is wron with the string  this doesn return anything  SELECT * FROM  jos_dhruprofile
WHERE
  department = 'IT'

Comment: Oh I found first flaw, the department values contain in some cases a space... Would it be safe to use LIKE .. ?

Comment: You might try Trim: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Comment: Its safety depends on your business requirements and the length of this field. This might work if you can guarantee that '%IT%' will never match any other record. If somebody inserts any word containing 'IT' in that column then your code will break. Personally, I would clean up the DB and fix the bug in the application that inserted the record. Or run a job periodically that trims these records, if you can't change the application that inserted the record.